# Bootstrap button flying over navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have navbar and button with bootstrap, class for them are as follows
 button-> `class="btn btn-primary` 
nav:-> `class="navbar navbar-default shadow"`

navbar inside div with

```
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
```

bootstrap button and other bootstrap content flying over navbar.How to fix ?
(Note using another css framework w3css with bootstrap.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add z-index something like `z-index: 999;` to the div and try